# Sql Insert statement return "zero/no rows inserted"

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert

I am writing an `INSERT` Statement to insert one row into the table in a PL/SQL block.  If this insert fails or no row is inserted then I need to rollback the previously executed update statement.

I want to know under what circumstances the `INSERT` statement could insert 0 rows.  If the insert fails due to some exception, I can handle that in the exception block.  Are there cases where the `INSERT` might run successfully but not throw an exception where I need to check whether `SQL%ROWCOUNT < 1`?

Comment: Is your `INSERT` statement an `INSERT ... VALUES` statement?  Or an `INSERT ... SELECT`?

Comment: My INSERT statement is like: INSERT ... VALUES

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your `INSERT` statement is structured as an `INSERT ... VALUES`, then it will either successfully insert exactly one row or generate an exception.  There would be no need to check the `SQL%ROWCOUNT`.

If your `INSERT` statement is structured as an `INSERT ... SELECT`, then it is possible that the `SELECT` statement will return 0 rows, the `INSERT` statement will insert 0 rows, and no exception will be thrown.  If you consider that to be an error, you would need to check the `SQL%ROWCOUNT` after the `INSERT` statement runs.

Comment: Excellent answer! I've always wondered how this could happen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, to find out how many rows are affected by DML statements (INSERT, UPDATES etc.), you can check the value of `SQL%ROWCOUNT`

```
INSERT INTO TABLE
SELECT col1, col2,....
  FROM TAB;

if SQL%ROWCOUNT=0 then
   RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'No records inserted');
end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

To complete one of above comments:

- in case if you request `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` DML statement without any hints, then indeed system will return either 1 row(s) created in case of success or ORA error in case of failure
- however if you request `INSERT INTO ... VALUES` DML statement with hint: IGNORE_ROW_ON_DUPE_KEY, then you get either 1 row(s) created or 0 row(s) created in case when the row already exists and ORA error in case of other failures
- and in case you request `INSERT ... SELECT` as mentioned above by Justin, you can also expect to get 0 row(s) created as internal call to SELECT can indeed return